# Correct way to configure CentOS7 NAT router?

Tags: centos, firewall, router, nat, private-network

## The Background

I have searched and scoured the web for information on the proper configuration of a NAT host running CentOS7 and firewalld for more than one private network.

I have a working environment for the main effort; that is, all the hosts can access the internet through the NAT host.

However, I want to understand what steps did what, why all the private hosts can communicate with all of the other private subnets.  I initially assumed the private hosts would be firewalled off from the other private networks, but now understand-- or assume-- that my configuration just opened up the private side of the network to each other.

## The Question(s)

- What is the best resource out there on `firewalld` that doesn't read like a TL;DR manual?
- When configuring the NAT hosts as stated below, am I correct in my understanding that the FORWARD and ACCEPT rules I provided are allowing the mentioned networks to communicate with ANY private network the NAT gateway knows about?

**host 01**: gateway (on VMware Fusion)
CentOS7 running `firewalld` (Host 01)
 - ens33 (Public network, 192.168.0.200/24)
 - ens37 (Private network #1 - 192.168.1.200/24)
 - ens38 (Private network #2 - 192.168.11.1/24)
 - ens39 (Private network #3 - 192.168.12.1/24)

Goal:

- I want to not only allow normal NAT services for all private networks (which is working fine), but I want to allow only the Private networks #2 & #3 to communicate with each other.
- I don't want them (#2 or #3) to communicate to network #1 at this time.

## The Detail - Steps I've completed configuring firewalld and the host

***Allowed forwarding***
I modified the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file with the following:
`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
*and after reloading sysctl.conf via `sysctl -p`, confirmed it is active since `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` holds a value of 1.*

***added zones***
`firewall-cmd --permanent --add-zone=vmnet3`
`firewall-cmd --permanent --add-zone=vmnet4`

***added interfaces to appropriate zones***
`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-interface=ens33`
`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=internal --add-interface=ens37`
`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=vmnet3 --add-interface=ens38`
`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=vmnet4 --add-interface=ens39`

***turned on masquerading***
`firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE`

***Added rules for the private networks (internal zone)***
*Am I correct in that this allows the NAT host to route the traffic to the internet?  Does it have an effect on intranetwork communication between the private networks (ens37, 38, & 39 interfaces)?*

`firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i ens37 -o ens33 -j ACCEPT`

`firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i ens33 -o ens37 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i ens38 -o ens33 -j ACCEPT`

`firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i ens33 -o ens38 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i ens39 -o ens33 -j ACCEPT`

`firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i ens33 -o ens39 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I am sorry if this not helpful because you've done your research and determined CentOS is the best tool for your use case, but why not use a router OS distribution, like Zeroshell, or another router Linux, where all these issues have been ironed our long, long time ago?

Comment: I did look into a router appliance, but this was not overly complex (or at least I thought).  

But, even if I did go with the router appliance option, I'm not really learning the **_why_** or the **_how_**, which is really why I'm asking.   

I was hoping, if a simple answer, someone with the knowledge could share, or, if the answer is complex, for someone with the knowledge could point me in the direction of a resource that isn't overly wordy or provide the nth degree of information like a manual (as I'm not sure what is important or not with a manual--it takes _forever_ to go through).